# CocoaPods not working on framework target

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

Im building a IOS app that uses a third-party library.

The library project is inherited from another developer that im unable to ask anything.

It is configured to use CocoaPods to manage dependencies, it has a lot of them.

When i run "pod install" it downloads all of them and creates the workspace.

In the workspace i have set the app target as dependent from the framework project product

Then i try to build it and it says it cannot find one of the dependencies of the framework project (it is on the podfile)

Then i found the framework project is missing "[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks" in build phases  (the app project has it)

Also the "Pods_[targetName].framework" is shown in red (even when it indeed is in the build products folder, the path is correct)

I found [this issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6123) that seems to be exactly my problem but im unable to see if it has been fixed or not and what could i do to workaround this.

Answer (score 0):

Same effect for me, my issue was the s.source_files in the podspec did not reference a location with actual files after a refactor.